# factorial function for Church numerals

Tags: clojure, lambda, functional-programming, factorial, y-combinator

I'm trying to implement the factorial lambda expression as described in the book [Lambda-calculus, Combinators and Functional Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521114292)

The way it's described there is :

```
fact = (Y)λf.λn.(((is-zero)n)one)((multiply)n)(f)(predecessor)n
Y = λy.(λx.(y)(x)x)λx.(y)(x)x
```

where

```
(x)y is equivalent to (x y) and
(x)(y)z is equivalent to (x (y x)) and
λx.x is equivalent to (fn [x] x)
```

and `is-zero`, `one`, `multiply` and `predecessor` are defined for the standard church numerals. Actual definitions [here](http://pastie.org/5541183).

I translated that to the following

```
(defn Y-mine [y]        ;  (defn Y-rosetta [y]              
  ((fn [x] (y (x x)))   ;    ((fn [f] (f f))                
    (fn [x]             ;     (fn [f]                       
      (y                ;       (y (fn [& args]             
        (x x)))))       ;            (apply (f f) args))))))
```

and

```
(def fac-mine                                ; (def fac-rosetta
  (fn [f]                                    ;      (fn [f]
    (fn [n]                                  ;        (fn [n]
      (is-zero n                             ;          (if (zero? n)
        one                                  ;            1
        (multiply n (f (predecessor n))))))) ;            (* n (f (dec n)))))))
```

The commented out versions are the equivalent fac and Y functions from [Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Clojure).

**Question 1:**

I understand from reading up elsewhere that the `Y-rosetta` β-reduces to `Y-mine`. In which case why is it preferable to use that one over the other?

**Question 2:**

Even if I use `Y-rosetta`. I get a StackOverflowError when I try

```
((Y-rosetta fac-mine) two)
```

while

```
((Y-rosetta fac-rosetta) 2)
```

works fine.

Where is the unguarded recursion happening?

I suspect it's something to do with how the `if` form works in clojure that's not completely equivalent to my `is-zero` implementation. But I haven't been able to find the error myself.

Thanks.

**Update:**

Taking into consideration @amalloy's answer, I changed `fac-mine` slightly to take lazy arguments. I'm not very familiar with clojure so, this is probably not the right way to do it. But, basically, I made `is-zero` take anonymous zero argument functions and evaluate whatever it returns.

```
(def lazy-one (fn [] one))
(defn lazy-next-term [n f]
  (fn []
    (multiply n (f (predecessor n)))))

(def fac-mine                       
  (fn [f]                           
    (fn [n]                         
      ((is-zero n                   
        lazy-one                    
        (lazy-next-term n f))))))
```

I now get an error saying:

```
=> ((Y-rosetta fac-mine) two)
ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core$lazy-next-term$fn  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

Which seems really strange considering that `lazy-next-term` is always called with `n` and `f`

Answer (score 1):

The body of `fac-mine` looks wrong: it's calling `(is-zero n one)` for side effects, and then unconditionally calling `(multiply n (f (predecessor n)))`. Presumably you wanted a conditional choice here (though I don't see why this doesn't throw an arity exception, given your definition of `is-zero`).

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake copying the code over. I've corrected it now. But I think the point about unconditionally calling `multiply` still holds. Is there a way to make that lazy?

Comment: Note that recursion (the use of the fixpoint operator) is not needed to define factorial on Church numerals.